# Rolling datediff over rows, multiple keys

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datediff

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

| Part | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 9/1/2021 |
| 1 | 9/8/2021 |
| 1 | 9/15/2021 |
| 2 | 9/1/2020 |
| 2 | 9/12/2020 |
| 2 | 9/14/2020 |

The dataframe is already sorted by part, then by date.

I need to calculate the days between each date in the previous row.

The date diff calculation would have to restart each time a new `part` row in encountered.

So the desired output would be:

| Part | Date | Diff |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 9/1/2021 |  |
| 1 | 9/8/2021 | 7 |
| 1 | 9/15/2021 | 7 |
| 2 | 9/1/2020 |  |
| 2 | 9/12/2020 | 11 |
| 2 | 9/14/2020 | 2 |

How would you go about processing this data to achieve the desired output?

Any assistance on this would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `groupby` + `diff`:

```
df.groupby('Part').Date.diff()

0       NaT
1    7 days
2    7 days
3       NaT
4   11 days
5    2 days
Name: Date, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

If you do not have `Date` as timestamp, you can use `df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)` to convert.

Comment: I get a TypeError: 'numpy.timedelta64' object is not iterable,. when trying this code.

Comment: @jmarusiak Can you share what's df.dtypes ?

Comment: Part                object
Date    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object

Comment: @jmarusiak hmm that's weird, you shouldn't get the error for this code.

Comment: nevermind, this worked, I just had to define as new column as such:
df["dif"] = df.groupby("Part").Date.diff()

Comment: Cool. Glad to know it works for you!